Data defined override not available in QGIS Model Designer
I'm trying to piece my workflow together into a model for my co-workers to use  while I am away this winter. Unfortunately a method I've been using does not seem to be translating to the Model Designer for some reason.
I've been generating points at discrete intervals along pieces of shoreline for some survey work using "Points Along Geometry."  Thus far it has worked great, as I've been able to use the data defined override feature to set different interval lengths and start offsets based on another set of fields  in the attribute table.
I thought it may have been because the model was producing a temporary output, but having it create a new shapefile to run the Points Along Geometry tool on does not seem to matter. I even tested it in a blank model with nothing but the Points tool in it, and while it detects the input shapefile, it does not allow you to use the data defined override.




Add a Vector Field input to your model,
Set its parent layer to your line layer,
Set the distance expression of Points along geometry to attribute(@vector_field)

When you execute the model you will be able to set the distance to any numeric column from the input line layer:


This worked! Thanks so much. In the future I'd be interested in using an mid-model output as one of these attribute inputs, do you know if that's possible? In my test runs it seems as though I can only use the pre-loaded shapefiles as the Vector inputs.
I am generating a new field of random values and would like to use them as the Start Offset.

Calculate the field, set the offset in points along geometry to Value (the default option) and set the expression to "yourfieldnamehere"

Click on the 123 Button and choose pre-calculated value, then enter your expression as you would in data defined override. See https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html#definition-of-the-workflow
